# Is there a multi-devices mobile prototyping software?

Tags: android, ios, windows, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro

Almost everything is in the title.

Is there a multi devices mobile prototyping, layout, templating software for Windows ?

I found many softwares for prototyping, designing UI, but i didn't find any which can handle all kind of mobile devices and export the template to each appropriate SDK.

Any idea ? Or this is too much for 1 software :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the best Prototyping tool is [Balsamiq](http://www.balsamiq.com/) .Which has custom library for Android,IOS,Windows etc.

Comment: Hello, Yes ! I'm agree, i tried a lot of software and this is the best one ! Thanks ;)